# Help reducing loops with filter code

Tags: c#

The following code is very slow. I was wondering if you can help me speed it up.

```
private void filter(List<CheckBox> boxList)
        {
            // refLanguageTabs is a TabControl the Tabcount is 9
            for (int i = 0; i < refLanguageTabs.TabCount; i++)
            {
                Control[] ctrls = refLanguageTabs.TabPages[i].Controls.Find(refLanguageTabs.TabPages[i].Name + "Grid", true);
                DataGridView dgv = ctrls[0] as DataGridView;

                // average row count is 3000 
                for (int j = 0; j < dgv.RowCount; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < boxList.Count; k++)
                    {
                        if (dgv.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString() != boxList[k].Name.ToString())
                        {
                            dgv.Rows[j].Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                dgv.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Only state the code purpose in the title, what does it do specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some few thoughts without testing or anything else:

- Cache the value of the cell in a local variable.
- [Replace for-loops if possible with foreach-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/for-vs-foreach-loop-in-c-sharp).
- The call of `boxList[x].Name.ToString()` is unnecessary, it is already a String.
- `break` after setting the visibility to avoid unnecessary checks.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    String cellValue = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    foreach(CheckBox boxItem in boxList)
    {
        if(cellValue == boxItem.Name)
        {
            row.Visible = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

On another sidenote, please use meaningful variable names, even in such stupid iterating loops.

Comment: Is there a speed difference between for and foreach?

Comment: Yes, there can be. With for() you have to use indexed arrays, and when you use indexed arrays the compiler has to emit code to check that your indexes are within the bounds of your array all the time. With foreach() you do not use indexed arrays, so you save those checks.

Comment: So I gather its like using iterators in c++ . . . .

Comment: @PoiXen: [The main reason is readability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/for-vs-foreach-loop-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Caching the value of the cell in a local variable and using `break` are indeed optimizations which could produce a perceptible difference. But I still bet that the optimization that I proposed (just 2 passes instead of N*M passes) should provide the greatest performance improvement.  Did you try it, @PoiXen?

Comment: Sorry, that should read 'just 2 passes instead of N passes'

Comment: @MikeNakis - my understanding is that for() is faster than foreach() despite the index bound checking. If you perform a Google search "for vs foreach performance" you would find that a lot of people would disagree with your statement.

Comment: @Marko I did the Google search that you suggested, and what I saw is that the answer to the question is still highly debatable, though most indications appear to suggest that for() will usually be somewhat faster, indeed.  So, I stand corrected.  But in any case, whatever performance difference there is, it will be negligible as far as the question at hand is concerned.  The better readability of the foreach() loop is almost always worth the few extra clock cycles.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to first make one pass through your cells and populate a dictionary in which the key is the name and the value is the cell itself. Then make a single pass through the checkboxes, and for each checkbox use its name to lookup the cell in the dictionary and there you have it.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this, thank you. It is a pity how the best answer is some times overlooked!  C-:=

Comment: What name do you mean to use for the key?

Comment: Hmmmm, I meant the value of the cell.  As in `MyDictionary[row.Cells[1].Value] = row.Cells[1]`

Comment: And what if there are multiple cells with the same value?

Comment: I did not know that was a possibility, but I suppose I should have thought of it. So, in that case, you can reverse it, assuming that you do not have two checkboxes with the same name. (Which sounds like a reasonable assumption to make.) First enumerate the checkboxes and populate a dictionary mapping checkbox names to checkboxes. Then, enumerate your rows, and look up the corresponding checkbox using the value of the cell.  This actually makes more sense, because I assume you have fewer checkboxes than rows, so the dictionary will take up less memory.

Comment: I had that thought already, you can go one step further and make a `List<String>` only containing the names, sort it and use a binary search against it...but if there are so many checkboxes that a binary search is needed, something is grossly wrong.

Comment: If you have more than a dozen checkboxes then a dictionary will probably perform better. But that's not the issue. The issue is this: if you are having performance problems with the sample code you showed, then obviously, something which is otherwise inconspicuous takes an awful long time. And the only things that can take a long time are 'dgv.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString()' and 'boxList[k].Name'. So, reducing the number of times these get executed should solve the performance problem.

Comment: In your code, these get executed roughly (NumberOfRows * NumberOfCheckboxes) times. In my proposal, they get executed roughly (NumberOfRows + NumberOfCheckboxes) times. That's a huge difference.

Comment: (I now notice you are not the OP, so I should not be saying "your code".)

Comment: You're aware that a Dictionary will need to look up that stuff, too, right? Even if it does that with a binary search, it still is `Rows*8` in the worst case. But if that's needed then there's something wrong with the overall design of the application.

Comment: The dictionary does not work with a binary search, it works in an even more efficient way, and it is said to achieve O(1) instead of O(log(N)), which is what binary search achieves. (This is not exactly so in practice, because there is a large constant factor, that's why we say that you see the improvement for N > a dozen.) But forget about that, the issue here is not dictionary vs. list.

Answer (score 1):

If you can stand a little LINQ and Task Parallel library, this might give it a little boost:

```
    private void filter(IEnumerable<CheckBox> boxList)
    {
        // refLanguageTabs is a TabControl the Tabcount is 9
        for (var i = 0; i < refLanguageTabs.TabCount; i++)
        {
            var ctrls = refLanguageTabs.TabPages[i].Controls.Find(refLanguageTabs.TabPages[i].Name + "Grid", true);
            var dgv = ctrls.Any() ? ctrls[0] as DataGridView : null;

            if (dgv == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // average row count is 3000
            Parallel.For(0, dgv.RowCount, j =>
            {
                foreach (var t in boxList.Where(t => dgv.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString() != t.Name.ToString()))
                {
                    dgv.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { dgv.Rows[j].Visible = false; }));
                }
            });

            dgv.Refresh();
        }
    }
```